# http://localhost:3000/getalldata/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

again am getting an error while fetching data from backend to frontend , don't know where am wrong please try to fix my error, if you have any query please free feel to ask.

[image: Output]

[image: Error]

[image: URL]

> Note :: My adddata Opeartion is working fine
>
> Userdata.js

This is my react js part where i want to fetch data from backend , and am using axios to fetch data

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link,useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Axios from 'axios';

const UserData = () => {
  const [users, setUser] = useState([{
    title : "",
    description : ""
  }]);
  
  const {id} = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    AllUsers();
  }, []);

  const AllUsers = async (id) => {
    const res = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/getalldata/${id}`);
    console.log(res.data);
    setUser(res.data)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-hover table-bordered mt-5">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {/* <th scope="col">No</th> */}
              <th scope="col">Title</th>
              <th scope="col">Details</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <th scope="row">{user.id}</th>
                <td>{user.title}</td>
                <td>{user.description}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserData;
```

> Userdata/Route

This is my route file

```
const express = require("express");
const route = express.Router();

const {
  getallData,
  addData,
  getDataById,
  deleteData,
  editData,
} = require('../controller/userdata');

route.get("/getalldata", getallData);
route.post("/adddata", addData);
route.get("/:id", getDataById);
route.delete("/:id", deleteData);
route.put("/editData/:id", editData);

module.exports = route;
```

> App.js

I have added App.js file which is link to each other.

```
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import UserData from "./components/UserData";
import AddData from "./components/AddData";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Register />} />
          <Route exact path="/signin" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/getalldata" element={<UserData />} />
          <Route exact path="/adddata" element={<AddData/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are not passing any params, you wont get any value while using `getParams()` so it will return undefined and which will be stored to `id` variable.

```
localhost:3000/getalldata
```

if your end point for all data looks like this , then you can avoid /${id} from url get request as you did in example code.

Comment: i did it as you said but still getting an same error

Comment: @TusharBhakare Is the 404 not found resolved? Kindly show the new error

Comment: i have added error page now you can checkout

Comment: @TusharBhakare please show the link to UserData component. Does it contain param id? Because still it is passed undefined!!

Comment: i have added the code that you want pleas check it.

Comment: I am asking about the url you paste in the browser.. not the code ... UseParams fetch the url value, i wanna make sure it is crct

Comment: i have added the url , those am using hitting to get alluserdata , i hope it will help you , still if you have any query please ask

Comment: So you are not passing any params? In that case you wont get any value while using getParams(). http://localhost:3000/getalldata if your end point for all data is like this , then you can avoid /${id} from get request... Try this

Comment: Yes Thank You so much @mathews Sunhy

Comment: @TusharBhakare if that wrked for you , kindly accept and upvote my updated answer. so let it help others